# Where and Order By clause not working

Tags: php

So this piece of code doesn't work and I can't figure it out.

```
$productid = (isset($_REQUEST['productId'])) ? $_REQUEST['productId'] : '';

$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productId = '$productid' ORDER BY rand() limit 3";
```

Comment: what does not work ? did you echo the query and see how it looks like and then tried on mysql directly ?

Comment: So if the productId doesn't come over, then you are SELECTing the products that don't have a productId. Is this intentional, and would a product not have an Id?

Comment: ...so are you getting an error message of some sort?

Comment: @StaticVoid yeah but everything has an Id so does that make a difference?

Comment: @ChrisWillard I'm not getting an error message just a blank screen

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I echoed the query and all it does is print out the same line nothing else

Comment: If you run it directly against the database as:
SELECT * FROM products WHERE productId = '' ORDER BY rand() limit 3

Your results will be the same, correct?

Comment: For a sanity check, you can put a known productId in the single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
$productid = (isset($_REQUEST['productId'])) ? $_REQUEST['productId'] : '';
if ($productid != ''){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productId = '$productid' ORDER BY rand() limit 3";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY rand() limit 3";
}
```

This should return all products if the productId isn't coming over.